# SQL Server : trigger AFTER INSERT,UPDATE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

In my database I have this trigger, it works but it looks really bad as a code.

The table `HOURS` contains an `idWork` historicized when user register your activity. Each user have assigned a personal `idWork`

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_HOURS_002]
   ON [dbo].[HOURS]
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    Update [HOURS] 
    set idWork = (select U.idWork 
                  from [USER] U
                  where U.id = (select inserted.idUser from inserted))
     where id = (select inserted.id from inserted)  
END
GO
```

Can you help me make it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `sub-query` to `JOIN`. Something like this.

```
UPDATE A
SET    idWork = b.idWork
FROM   [HOURS] A
       JOIN (SELECT U.idWork,
                    i.id
             FROM   [USER] U
                    JOIN inserted I
                      ON U.id = i.idUser) B
         ON a.id = b.id
```

Or

```
UPDATE A
SET    idWork = b.idWork
FROM   [HOURS] A
        JOIN inserted I
            ON a.id = I.id
        JOIN [USER] U
            ON U.id = i.idUser
```